# JUnit How to handle an expected fail?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I know that a part of my program will fail when I try and test it and I wan't the test to pass when it fails. So I was wondering if it is possible to assert a failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Junit 4, use the expected behavior:

```
@Test(expected=SomeException.class)
public void testThings() {
    // do stuff
}
```

If you're using Junit 3, you'll have to catch it

```
public void test() {
    try {
        // do stuff
        fail("Expected SomeException");
    } catch (SomeException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Junit 4 and I'm trying to have it expect NoSuchElementException but I don't think my syntax is right:
@Test(expected=NoSuchElementException)

EDIT: My bad I didn't import the exception. Thank you for help!

Comment: Cheers!  Enjoy testing!

Comment: Better to use `fail("Should have thrown exception!")` after `do stuff` instead of `assertTrue(passed)` - one less variable.

Comment: @Cebence - good suggestion.  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The JUnit wiki lists different ways of exception testing: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Exception-testing